# Python Pandas - How to group by one column, and combine the data of two other columns on each group on certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe as follows

| main key | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc | Value 1 |
| 123 | def | Value 2 |
| 123 | ghi | Value 3 |
| 456 | abc | Value 4 |
| 789 | NaN | Value 5 |
| 789 | NaN | Value 6 |
| 147 | NaN | Value 7 |

I want to apply the following logic:

1. Group by the values of 'main key' column
2. If the name column is not NaN, then make a new column 'dataAggregated' with 'name' and 'value' combined like a dictionary
3. If the name column is NaN, then make a new column 'dataAggregated' with the data in 'value' column separated by commas

(When it is grouped by 'main key', all the 'name' data will either have NaN or not have NaN. It wont be a mix of both while grouping)

The expected output dataframe should look like the following:

| main key | dataAggregated |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {'abc':'Value 1','def':'Value 2','ghi':'Value 3'} |
| 456 | {'abc':'Value 4'} |
| 789 | 'Value 5','Value 6' |
| 147 | 'Value 7' |

Any idea how this can be achieved?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom aggregation with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df
   .groupby('main key')
   .apply(lambda g: g.set_index('name')['value'].to_dict()
                    if g['name'].notna().all() else
                    ', '.join(g['value'])
         )
   .reset_index(name='dataAggregated')
)
```

Output:

```
   main key                                          dataAggregated
0       123  {'abc': 'Value 1', 'def': 'Value 2', 'ghi': 'Value 3'}
1       147                                                 Value 7
2       456                                      {'abc': 'Value 4'}
3       789                                        Value 5, Value 6
```